# Model doesn't show up on relationship right after saving?

Tags: laravel

For example

```
$user->transactions()->save($transaction);

dump($transaction->id); // id: 4
dd($user->transactions); // last id is 3
```

The `$transaction` that is saved does not show up in `$user->transactions`. This is a **polymorphic** relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save a model through a relationship, all Laravel does is set the appropriate foreign keys. It doesn't set the newly saved model to the relation or add it to a collection.

If you want the model with updated relations use the `fresh` function.

```
$user->transactions()->save($transaction);
$user = $user->fresh('transactions');
```

**Edit** answer updated following @JCLee's correction to assign the result of `$user->fresh()`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It's a polymorphic relationship if it makes any difference.

Comment: Hmm. I've not used `fresh` to reload relationships before, but this is what the source code suggests is the correct usage. https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L922

Comment: I figured out why. `$user->fresh('transactions');` returns the refreshed model but does not refresh the original model. So `$user = $user->fresh('transactions');` works.